# JNI DestroyJavaVM() Hangs Host Application on Exit

Tags: java-native-interface

When exiting my native C++ application I make a JNI call to DestroyJavaVM() and it hangs... eventually the application will close (about 10 - 15 minutes) once Java realizes the resources are no longer in use.  Not sure why it's hanging but I'm assuming there are objects that have not released memory on the JVM side.  Any way to force garbage collection on the JNI side of things?

Comment: Did you consider looking up the documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the relevant part of the [JNI Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#destroy_java_vm):

> If the current thread is not attached, the VM attaches the current
>   thread and then waits until the current thread is the only non-daemon
>   user-level thread.